# Eclipse generate JAXB classes - cowardly refuses to write to a non-existent directory "src"

Tags: java, jaxb

Following a JAXB tutorial using Eclipse JUNO EE I get the following on generating JAXB classes.

I believe I am following the steps, however searching the net returns very few results, any help is appreciated.

```
cowardly refuses to write to a non-existent directory "src"

Usage: xjc [-options ...] <schema file/URL/dir/jar> ... [-b <bindinfo>] ...
If dir is specified, all schema files in it will be compiled.
If jar is specified, /META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode binding file will be compiled.
Options:
  -nv                :  do not perform strict validation of the input schema(s)
  -extension         :  allow vendor extensions - do not strictly follow the
                        Compatibility Rules and App E.2 from the JAXB Spec*
```

Answer (score 1):

The ***-d***  parameter [says](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) that *"The output directory must already exist, the XJC binding compiler will not create it for you."*

The src directory must be there or the xjc library will refuses [cowardly](http://peter-eichenauer.de/safari/blog/entry/cowardly_refuses).